# Best way to handle component loading in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, loading, jsonplaceholder

I've an app that gets posts from **JSONPlaceholder**. It has an initial state of posts: []. It then calls:

```
this.setState({posts})
```

If I want to render loading... before the component receives the posts, is it better to say:

```
if (!this.state.posts.length) // Do something
```

or it's better to add loading: true to initial state then said this if the component received data without error:

```
if(!this.state.loading) // Do something
```

Comment: Showing a loader on state.loading is a good way in my opinion since it will allow you to show loader if you are loading more records to the state.posts when state.posts.length is non zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as the comment said, use a single `boolean type state` is better than use a `changeable condition` everywhere.

If you want to add some `loading animation`, I've tried [Material-UI processing](https://material-ui.com/components/progress/) sometimes and it's convenient.

And the usage is quite simple in this situation. Add a [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) and it's done.

```
import { CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
...
render() {
  const { loading } = this.state;
  return (
    ...
    {loading ? <CircularProgress /> : <YourComponent /> ... 
    ...
  )
}
```